# How to specify language for x-ray npm webscraping?

Tags: node.js, npm, web-scraping, x-ray

#### Subject of the issue

E.g. i want to scrape a book page from play market. Google market is available in multiple languages without url-specific markers. So, how can i scrape the specific version with language i need instead of random one?

#### Environment

"x-ray": "^2.2.0"
node --version: 5.9.0
npm --version: 3.7.3

#### Steps to reproduce

Try to scrape any page from play market. This one for example:
https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Walter_Isaacson_Steve_Jobs?id=I6R8MXStPXgC

#### Expected behaviour

Page is scraped with specific language

#### Actual behaviour

It scrapes random language (swedish, spanish, portuges - all this while i'm running x-ray from the same VPS)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a querystring parameter "hl" to define a two-letter language code. So to get the page in Chinese for example, use the url:

https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Walter_Isaacson_Steve_Jobs?id=I6R8MXStPXgC&hl=zh

Note the **&hl=zh** appended to your original url.